# How to enable User Account SMB sharing from terminal on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, cocoa, bash, terminal

I'm trying to enable **Account Sharing** from terminal. I can't figure out how to do that.

This will be used from inside an application I'm currently programming. The application creates a hidden user, then should enable SMB sharing for this user. Later, I need to connect to this share via another server using SMB.

I need **the same effect** as going to *System Preferences → Sharing →  File Sharing →*  enable any account for sharing using SMB.

[image]

---

**What I already have:**

- I know how to create a hidden user
- I already know how to create individual shared folders, but not account sharing.

**What I've already tried:**

- I already tried to scan the system for last modified files to find some information in Samba config files, but it didn't help.

**What I don't need:**

- I can't do this with SSH. The folders *need* to be shared via SMB.

Comment: You can probably enable it with: `sudo launchctl start com.apple.smbfs_load_kext`, but at the moment, I don't know how more. What is your exact use case?

Comment: I need to share some folders.AFter need to enable SMB sharing on specific user , that I have created. So I need a way to enable sharing to a specific user from terminal. Like you can do it from System Preferences->Sharing.

Comment: @melee I need to do it for OS X 10.5 ,10.6 ,10.7 .. But if you have idea how to do that on any of them, it would be really great. Thanks

Comment: @User1234 SMBD in 10.7 was rewritten completely. Just a heads up.

Comment: @melee Yes I know. but it still use Directory Service for handling Sharings. Do you have an idea how to do that/ do you have an idea how to do that on 10.6?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**THIS WORKS FOR OS X 10.5, 10.6, 10.7**

First type this in terminal

```
pwpolicy -u SomeUser -sethashtypes SMB-NT on
```

`SomeUser` can also be hidden, it doesn't matter. This gives the same effect like enabling that checkbox as shown in the picture above.

After that:

```
dscl . -passwd /Users/SomeUser "UserPassword"
```

This gives the same effect, as enabling it from System Preferences, when it asks for a password. It's the same like filling in that password.

If you want to disable SMB on that account (`SomeUser` can be hidden again):

```
pwpolicy -u SomeUser -sethashtypes SMB-NT off
```

P.S. In Mac OS X Lion, they changed their implementation for SMB (SMBX). But be aware that it still uses the same Share Points mechanism for creating a share, and Directory Service is responsible for it. Also it still works the same way for enabling SMB on account!

Comment: Nice! Thanks for updating this - I was curious too after trying to get this figured out.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the answer above in 10.7 and I was happy to see that after the SMB-NT on, the setting appeared effectively on in the Sharing Options screen.

The problem is that being that user enabled with that method I could not connect from Windows. So I had to try another esoteric solution that I had found before and I didn't want to try:

- Is about changing the /var/db/dslocal/nodes/Default/users/.plist file reordering the authentication_authority array values.

Here is the full explanation:
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3211072?start=0&tstart=0

After making that change, the user smb setting was again OFF (maybe because I used a .plist old file), but I was able to effectively turn it ON and to connect from Windows!

Answer (score 1):

> sudo launchctl load -w
>   /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist
>
> sudo defaults write
>   /Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/com.apple.smb.server.plist
>   EnabledServices -array disk

This could be one other way.

And to disable it again, - unload it.

> sudo launchctl unload -w
>   /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.smbd.plist